# Play and record midi stream simultaneously

Tags: midi

I have a Yamaha Clavinova CLP-230 piano, which can export MIDI through the usb cable to my Ubuntu computer. I can play piano and record the data to midi file with a `arecordmidi -p 24:0 test.mid` command. I can play the recorded file with `timidity test.mid`.

The problem above is that CLP-230 is mute when midi usb export is selected. Is there a way to play the stream without saving it first to the file? I tried to pipe the `arecordmidi`command with `timidity` but did not find the acceptable notation.

SOLUTION (See @CL comment): First I have to find appropriate ports with e.g. command `aplaymidi -l`. In my case then a simple command `aconnect 24:0 128:0` and the play can be heard from the computer. 
If I want to record the file at the same time, I just open the other terminal to do that.

Comment: Enable "Local Control". Or connect the MIDI port to the Timidity port with `aconnect`.

Comment: Thanks @ CL of your comment. For me it was an answer. It directed me to right direction.